# Integration Test Accounts

Tags: google-classroom

We built our first Google Classroom integration, and to do so we requested test accounts.  Now that our application is integrated, we've like to be able to write automated integration tests to ensure that the integration continues to work.

During the Google Classroom session at SXSWedu, I was told it is possible for us to request that our company's domain be allowed to use Google Classroom (even though we aren't eligible for the Google Apps for Education) for this purpose.  How do we go about requesting this access?

Comment: have you been able to solve this problem? We have the same question and have been searching all around. The documentation page which appears to have had this information before no longer gives useful information. https://developers.google.com/classroom/access#get_classroom_test_accounts

Comment: yes, we were able to request test accounts from Google.  That being said... we ended ran into a different problem after we had our accounts, which is that after building the integration tests (mostly for logging in and  signing up), Google started flagging our authentication as suspicious because of the frequency of requests.  We were hit with two-factor authentication and captchas, which made it impossible to build integration tests for.

Comment: Wow thanks @Dennis, good to know.  Do you know how you were able to request accounts?

Comment: I got a response from a Google Classroom product manager, who gave us some instructions.  First step was to purchase a new domain with the format gedu-demo-[developername].com. (For example, if your company is EdSmart, sign-up for gedu-demo-edsmart.com

We then had to verify our domain ownership with Google:
https://support.google.com/a/answer/60216?hl=en

Then we had to fill out the following request form:
https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLScFnnpQCCbqw-Phwv3ZOkFkSRnH7JhpyBgPl15M_oZBbC3FjA/viewform

This all happened over a year ago, so not sure if this is still valid

Comment: @Dennis How did you get a Google for Education contact?

Comment: I attended a conference (I want to say SXSWedu) and happened to get a business card from one of the product managers who was leading a session on Google Classroom integration that day.